# Parsing JSON file with Freddy SDK

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I'm struggling to get some values in the correct format when parsing a JSON file using the [Freddy SDK](https://github.com/bignerdranch/Freddy), I'm trying to parse some questions and answers from a quiz with the JSON like so:

```
  {
      "success":true,
      "quiz":[
              {
              "question":"Which of the following is required by law?",
              "answers":[
                         ["To have your dog microchipped and correct details.", true],
                         ["To have your dog wear a collar and tag with correct contact details.", true],
                         ["To register your dog with the local Dog Warden.", false],
                         ["To pick up after your dog.", true]
                         ],
              "imageFileName":"ChippedDog.jpg"
              }
             ]
  }
```

The trouble I'm having is with getting the answers and their Bool values. My parsing code is:

```
func createQuestionObjectsFromJSON() -> [Question] {

    self.questions = []
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: self.fileName, ofType: self.fileType)
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!) {
        do {
            let json = try JSON(data: data as Data)
            for questionJSON in try json.getArray(at:"quiz") {

                var question = Question()
                question.text = try questionJSON.getString(at: "question")
                question.answers = try questionJSON.getArray(at: "answers") as [AnyObject]
                question.imageFileName = try questionJSON.getString(at: "imageFileName")
                self.questions?.append(question)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error parsing questions part of JSON file")
        }
    }

    return questions

}
```

but then when I try to access each answer in my cellForRow at I can't.

if call

`let answer = currentQuestion.answers[indexPath.row]`

then print it I get

`[To have your dog microchipped and correct details., true]`

but the first value isn't a string as it should be and if I call

`answer[0]`

i get nil. I'm a little lost and sure there's an easy fix but i just can't see it.

Any help would be great.

Update: Qustion struct:

import UIKit

```
struct Question {

    var text: String!
    var answers: [AnyObject]!
    var imageFileName: String!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try  `question.answers = try questionJSON.getArray(at: "answers") as [Array]`

instead of   **:** 
 `question.answers = try questionJSON.getArray(at: "answers") as [AnyObject]`

Comment: If i do this then call `answer[0]` i get the error `type "Any" has no subscript members`

Comment: you need to modify your struct Question accordingly

Comment: i changed the struct Question to `var answers: Array<Any>!` and thats what gave me the above error